# Is it safe to delete stuff in /usr/src ?

Tags: filesystem

After `apt-get upgrade` and -`update`, my 4 GB SD-card was full. I already ran 'apt-get clean' to clear uit `/var` but I still have less than 1 GB free and I'd like to free up more space.

The update took me from raspbian version 3.6 to 3.10. Running `du -sh /usr/src/*` gives me this:

```
1.1G    /usr/src/linux-source-3.2
75M     /usr/src/linux-source-3.2.tar.bz2
79M     /usr/src/linux-source-3.6.tar.bz2
```

Looking at the version numbers, can I delete these without causing trouble later on?

I got the idea from [this topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1284341), a similar issue on Ubuntu. I think I don't need older versions of source code, but I want to be 100.00% sure.

Comment: you should get a bigger card, 16G/Class10 is a commodity nowadays.

Comment: @lenik I already have several bigger cards, even. I'm asking the question because (1) I want to keep using all features on this one without having to redo all the interior decorating it underwent in the past few years, and (2) isn't one of Linux' benefits its nice small footprint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking at the version numbers, can I delete these without causing trouble later on?

Yes, this is just source code for the kernel.  Presuming you are not compiling it there or using it for some other purpose, you don't need it.  The system does not use it for anything.

Debian by default does not install the kernel source, so you must have added the package at some point.  Try:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-source
```

"linux-source" is the basename of the source packages.  If anything turns up, use `apt-get remove` on it.  If that doesn't clear out `/usr/src`, you can just mass delete whatever is left.

Comment: Many thanks, just the answer I hoped for. I have no idea how that source got there. Don't recall installing it.